# How to import data from Oracle into Hive table using a query in sqoop command

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have this particular query in Oracle

> select count(*) from call.CALL_IVR_DETAIL_FACT where customer_key IN (select distinct CUSTOMER_KEY FROM EDW.WORK_ORDER_DAILY_FACT WHERE WO_CHECKED_IN_DT_KEY  BETWEEN '20141001' AND '20141031' AND WO_TYPE_KEY = '7' AND OFFICE_ONLY_FLAG_KEY <> '2') AND TIME_KEY  BETWEEN '01-OCT-14' AND '31-OCT-14'

I need to import the results of this query from Oracle into Hive table.

My sqoop command is as follows

> sqoop import --connect 'xxxx' --username xxx--password xxxx--query 'select * from call.CALL_IVR_DETAIL_FACT where customer_key IN (select distinct CUSTOMER_KEY FROM EDW.WORK_ORDER_DAILY_FACT WHERE WO_CHECKED_IN_DT_KEY  BETWEEN '20141001' AND '20141031' AND WO_TYPE_KEY = '7' AND OFFICE_ONLY_FLAG_KEY <> '2') AND TIME_KEY  BETWEEN '01-OCT-14' AND '31-OCT-14' AND $CONDITIONS' -m 1   --hive-import --hive-table CALL_IVR_DETAIL_FACT --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/call_ivr_detail_fact

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "OCT": invalid identifier
>
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "OCT": invalid identifier

Is the query that I have inserted correct?

What should I change?

Any help would be great!

Comment: looks like issue with date format, are u getting records when u run first query in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports):

> The facility of using free-form query in the current version of Sqoop is limited to simple queries where there are no ambiguous projections and no OR conditions in the WHERE clause. Use of complex queries such as queries that have sub-queries or joins leading to ambiguous projections can lead to unexpected results.

Seems like your free-form query is missing `$CONDITIONS` from the `WHERE` clause. Also, it might be a bit too complex for Sqoop to manage.